# Android how to write like 'Voice Accessibility'

Tags: android, accessibility

I want to write a function, like Google Voice Accessibility can search screen objects node and display commands on the objects position, how can I use android AccessibilityService to do it, thank you.

Voice Accessibility Demo image:
[image: voice accessibility demo]